# Land on certain element of another page from clicking link

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I need help landing on a certain id or class (on another page) once clicking a link. Once clicking on a link on a page, the user lands on another page on a specific part of that new page on a specific id or class.

I understand this can be done by the pixel screen but can it be done to land user on the element?

Comment: Normally that's what anchors are for. Is there some reason you can't just use an anchor tag? <a name="gohere">Go Here</a> then your href of your link would look like <a href="newpage#gohere">link</a>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to direct the user to an id on the landing page like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com#some-id">Link to #some-id</a>
```

For this page, you could point the user at the answers id like so:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32896613/land-on-certain-element-of-another-page-from-clicking-link/32896654#answers">Link to answers</a>
```

Comment: Cool! I've rarely seen this but it's so nice to know it's this simple

Comment: @Jnsn_ Great to know I could help. Could you accept the answer as correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have a clickable button with a link EXEMPLE.html

and EXEMPLE.html have an element with id AZERTY , and you want to land on that element directly do add this to your link

> EXEMPLE.html#AZERTY

Answer (score 0):

Yo just need to pass the ID of your element within your URL.

**Here I made an example for you:** It is the same page and you can send the user to any of your sections passing the Ids of the containers

http://run.plnkr.co/938MixSbG10TiYMo/#element-1

http://run.plnkr.co/938MixSbG10TiYMo/#element-2

http://run.plnkr.co/938MixSbG10TiYMo/#element-3

*Here you can see the HTML code to edit it:* http://plnkr.co/edit/mSWBzT3c9jHRuPZHlRfh

```
  <body>
    <nav>
    <a href="http://plnkr.co/edit/mSWBzT3c9jHRuPZHlRfh#element-1">element 1</a>
    <a href="http://plnkr.co/edit/mSWBzT3c9jHRuPZHlRfh#element-2">element 2</a>
    <a href="http://plnkr.co/edit/mSWBzT3c9jHRuPZHlRfh#element-3">element 3</a>
    </nav>
    <section id="element-1">section 1</section>
    <section id="element-2">section 2</section>
    <section id="element-3">section 3</section>
  </body>
```